# c# datetimeoffset json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, c#-4.0, datatable

I am querying a table no craziness just regular select, the table has a datetimeoffset(7) then using for json. The json result is being send to a different database with the same schema for the table including the datetimeoffset(7) but when i deserialize the json and do the insert in c# i am getting different time formats.

c# to datatable

```
DataTable data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(messageData["Records"].ToString());
```

example date results when two tables are unioned together

```
select LastUpdateTimestamp from sourcetable
where id = 1
union 
select LastUpdateTimestamp from destinationtable
where id = 1
```

[image]

The query result from sql server querying the source table

```
select LastUpdateTimestamp from sourcetable where id = 1
```

[image]

The for json auto result is

[{"LastUpdateTimestamp":"2017-06-21T08:12:16.1430000Z"}]

The query on the destination table yeilds

```
select LastUpdateTimestamp from destinationtable where id= 1
```

[image]

messageData["Records"].ToString() is

```
[{"timestamp1":"2017-05-24T10:18:00.0000000Z","timestamp2":"2017-05-24T15:15:00.0000000Z","CreateTimestamp":"2017-06-21T08:12:16.1420000Z","LastUpdateTimestamp":"2017-06-21T08:12:16.1430000Z"}]
```

I will note sql server 2016 to azure sql db

Query that returns the shortened datetimeoffset

```
select LastUpdateTimestamp from table
where UnifiedCustomerRequestID = 1
for json auto
```

the for json auto returns as 2017-06-21T08:12:16.1430000Z instead of the offset.

I have added a datetimeoffset converter in my c# code, it is still missing the milliseconds for some reason but gets to the correct format (other than milliseconds).

Comment: What's the value of `messageData["Records"].ToString()`?

Comment: I took other data elements out and scrubbed the names of the timestamp columns but i edited post to show. ill add the sql server side

Comment: Please post your query that uses  "for json auto". it seems like data type issue (date vs datetime)

Comment: @KashifQureshi added the query